# Automatically build a form using entity (one to one relationship)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, formbuilder

I'm wondering if it is possible to build a form using an entity to get all the fields, in a one-to-one relationship. To clarify:

I have an `User.php` entity (with all the obvious fields, name, surname, genre, etc) and a `Address.php` entity. What I want is to build the whole form without adding one by one the properties of Address entity and save it with the proper relationship in the database.

This is what I've tried (i've trimed the code a little bit), but obviously is not the correct way:

User entity:

```
class User implements UserInterface {

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;


/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, nullable=TRUE)
 */
protected $firstName;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=200)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
protected $lastNames;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Capsa\Bundle\ClubCommonBundle\Entity\Address")
 */
protected $address;
```

Address class

```
class Address {

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, unique=TRUE)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
protected $streetName;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
 */
protected $streetNumber;
```

Form builder:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('login', 'text')
            ->add('password', 'password')
            ->add('firstName', 'text', array("required" => FALSE))
            ->add('lastNames', 'text')
            ->add('address', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'CapsaClubCommonBundle:Address',
                'property'=>'streetName'
            ));
}
```

That only gets the field streetName of the table and puts it in a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [Collection form type](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/collection.html) instead of Entity field type – see [this tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html).

Comment: finally I used just this to load the whole object: `->add('address', new AddressType());` of course, defyining AddressType

Comment: @Manu your comment is really the answer - al least the one that worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Following Manu's comment here is the newer syntax : ```->add('address', AddressType::class)```